# How to upgrade Alfresco 4.1.4 to 7.2?

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-enterprise

I tried installing Alfresco 7.2 via docker compose which is recommended way by alfresco for most of the people. I found it hard to customize so I went for the zip installation approach. In zip approach we require too many complex configs which are hard for beginner like me. Then I tried to search for readymade setups and exe's but alfresco does not provide .exe or any sample setup zip for latest versions. So what I need is how can I install alfresco as simple as .exe installation or any ready zip is appreciable. Otherwise step by step installation guide is also welcome.

Comment: Docker is much easier then zip installation. Have you tried this installer for docker? https://github.com/Alfresco/alfresco-docker-installer

Comment: @DavidDejmal thanks for the reply! yes I tried that, it was successful. But I want to customize it. I have custom jar files. I am struggling to change the setup, like custom solr properties, alfresco properties, database properties, deploying share jar. I struggle with finding paths where these properties files are located. I did "grep" too but no luck..

Comment: I would not confirm the statement "Docker is much easier then zip installation.". If your intention is to run more than an Alfresco Hello-World example, docker can even become more complicated and you need to know very well what you are doing. The complexity is just hidden and even harder to modify.

Comment: @HeikoRobert Agree with your point. I did the same but struggled a lot with the modification. Need more details on customized setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are options:

- [Setup ACS-7.x, ASS-2.x and Local Transformation Service using distribution package step by step Part-1 by Abhinav Kumar Mishra](https://javaworld-abhinav.blogspot.com/2021/06/setup-acs70-ass201-and-transformation-service.html)
- [Re: Upgrading Alfresco 4.1.4 to 7](https://hub.alfresco.com/t5/alfresco-content-services-forum/upgrading-alfresco-4-1-4-to-7/m-p/306833/highlight/true#M24093)
- [Alfresco Community packaged by Bitnami](https://bitnami.com/stack/alfresco)
- [Alfresco Virtual Appliance (CE or EE) maintained and supported by ecm4u](https://www.ecm4u.de/en/what-we-do/products/alfresco/alfresco-virtual-appliance)